# Insert timestamp posted value in mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have input where I get values like:

```
$water =    11/04/2013 00:00:00
```

(day/month/year) hour:minute:second

And a table definition:

```
CREATE  TABLE `my_to` (
    id_a        INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    last_time   timestamp   ,           
    water       timestamp       
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

but when I am trying to do an insert I get no value in the table...
Should I convert the day or something?

supposing $water has a date and time value?

```
$timestamp = strtotime($water);
```

Insert into table ....  $timestamp   ?

Comment: show us how you are trying to insert it.. How you escape it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Correct syntax is: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

so ..

```
$time = '11/04/2013 00:00:00'; 
$time = strtotime($time);
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
# INSERT TIME...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use MySQL's `STR_TO_DATE` function:

```
INSERT INTO `table`( `date_field` )
VALUES( STR_TO_DATE( $water, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S' );
```

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp you want to insert must have the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS`.

You can use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($water))`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps in mysql must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS format. You can do this in php with

```
Date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($water))
```

You could also use the FROM_UNIXTIME mysql function

Answer (score 0):

```
water DATETIME
```

or fill the field with NOW() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `strtotime()` interprets that date in the format `mm/dd/YYYY`, and not as `dd/mm/YYYY`.
You should rearrange date in a different format (`YYYY-mm-dd` would be the best, imho).